# VDDCORE & ENVREG connection when it is not used

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I have 2 PIC18 chips the first one :
1- PIC18F46K80 working with 5V supplied from external regulator, it has a VDDCORE pin.
2- PIC18F65J90 working with 3.3V supplied from external regulator, it has VDDCORE & ENVREG pins.
I read the datasheet more than once and I didn't come to a clear point.
The question is what should I do with those pins? because i am not using the internal regulator feature. Should I tide them to ground or just let them float, Or what should I do?

Comment: Voltage on VDDCORE with respect to VSS -0.3V to 2.75V.  that is from the datasheet

Comment: Section 2.4 of the PIC18F65J90 databook clearly describes the use of the VDDCORE and ENVREG pins.

Comment: you mean section 22.3? the one tells that when internal regulator disabled VDDcore must be connected to 2.5V and ENVREG connected to VSS? I have read that but I find it a little bit weird , I must make a 2.5 Voltage in my circuit to tide it to VDDcore just because I am not using it, is not a little bit strange.

Comment: No, I meant section 2.4 - but that section does refer you to 23.3 and 26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The microprocessor *core* runs on 2.5 volts.  The I/O pins and other peripheral logic can be run from a higher voltage (VDD).  VDD does not supply power to the core.  You must supply your own 2.5 volts, or use the built-in regulator to get it.  There is no option to not supply voltage to the processor core.

Now the disposition of ENVREG is apparent.  If you use the internal regulator, tie it to VDD.  If you don't, then tie it to ground.

Comment: That is good, thank you.  

One last thing: if I didn't connect VDDcore and left it float, the PIC will not operate?

Comment: Yes.  That's the way I understand it.

Comment: I had already said to @brhans I had used PIC18F46k80 and I didn't paid attention to VDDcore and left it unconnected, the circuit worked fine, that was in testing board. Now I am moving to PCB so I have to be sure every thing is fine. 
Any way your answer was very clear and delivered the idea to my mind directly, thank you

Comment: Or the capacitor must be connected between VDDcore and ground is to bypass the noise and luckily my circuit didn't affected by the noise so i worked?

Comment: Yes, if you had the voltage regulator enabled.  The 2.5v from the regulator will appear on the VDDcore pin, and you (should) attach a capacitor to filter it.  I once tried leaving the cap off in a similar situation with USB, and it didn't work without it.  So, yes, lucky (until they start failing, randomly, in the field!)

Comment: I had made PCB with 40 pin DIP, and through a header, the first one worked well, the second one failed, the third one worked. NOW I have know the reason

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the PIC18F65J90 is a part of the PIC18F85J90 family.

In section 23.3 On-Chip Voltage Regulator of the datasheet:

> All of the PIC18F85J90 family devices power their core
>   digital logic at a nominal 2.5V. For designs that are
>   required to operate at a higher typical voltage, such as
>   3.3V, all devices in the PIC18F85J90 family incorporate
>   an on-chip regulator that allows the device to run its
>   core logic from VDD.

So that says the core digital logic modules need 2.5V.

> The regulator is controlled by the ENVREG pin. Tying
>   VDD to the pin enables the regulator, which in turn, provides
>   power to the core from the other VDD pins. When
>   the regulator is enabled, a low-ESR filter capacitor
>   must be connected to the VDDCORE/VCAP pin
>   (Figure 23-2). This helps to maintain the stability of the
>   regulator. The recommended value for the filter capacitor
>   is provided in Section 26.3 “DC Characteristics:
>   PIC18F84J90 Family (Industrial)”.If ENVREG is tied to VSS, the regulator is disabled. In
>   this case, separate power for the core logic at a nominal
>   2.5V must be supplied to the device on the
>   VDDCORE/VCAP pin to run the I/O pins at higher voltage
>   levels, typically 3.3V. Alternatively, the VDDCORE/VCAP
>   and VDD pins can be tied together to operate at a lower
>   nominal voltage. Refer to Figure 23-2 for possible
>   configurations.

Figure 23-2 shows your three options to supply the digital logic modules with 2.5V.

[image]

Since you are supplying 3.3V, I would go with the first option and let the internal regulator provide the 2.5V for you. Tie ENVREG to 3.3V and use the appropriate Vcap.

Comment: I can not work with the 2.5V because this PIC is used for driving LCD, the LCD operating voltage is 3.3V, So i have to use the 3.3V only.

Comment: So I have to supply a 2.5V to VDDCORE as NOT TO USE the internal regulator ? is that right ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The core of these PICs runs from a 2.5V supply. This is not optional. If you don't want to use the internal 2.5V regulator, you *must* supply 2.5V to the PIC. But the PIC's IO pins do not use the core's 2.5V - the IO pins use your 3.3V Vdd. So give it 3.3V, enable the internal regulator, put a cap on VddCore, and all will be fine.

Comment: @brhans
If I didn't connect VDDcore to any thing will it work?

Comment: If you leave it floating - probably not reliably, if at all. It needs at least a capacitor to stabilize the internal regulator.

Comment: I had already worked with PIC18F46K80 the DIP, and I didn't pay attention to the VDDcore and left it unconnected, it worked fine, so I want to know what is the effect of that pin. 
And thank you for your answer, it was very clear

Comment: You probably successfully got away with it not connected to anything because all of the PIC18F66K80 family devices power their core digital logic at a nominal 3.3V, unlike the PIC18F65J90. So if you supplied the PIC18F46K80 with 3.3V, it would have still operated normally, although you should have still had a cap there.

Answer (score 0):

This was originally a comment*

VDD is the positive supply voltage pin. ENVREG is the On-Chip voltage regulator, that can be supplied with 5V, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: When the regulator is disabled, the VCAP/VDDCORE pin
must be tied to a voltage supply at the VDDCORE level.
Refer to Section 31.0 “Electrical Characteristics” for
information on VDD and VDDCORE.  But nothing about VDDcore pin in that section

Comment: Of course yes, forgot about that.